# Why doesn't the autocapitalize attribute work with non-virtual keyboards?

Tags: html

I just found that we can use this attribute to specify which case the letters should be entered in, but that doesn't work for me.

Example:

```html
<input type="text" autocapitalize="words" name="subject" value="Website Feedback" />
```

I set this attr to **words** but still type with lover case each new word, so how it should work?

Comment: Potentially relevant quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize): "The autocapitalize attribute doesn't affect behavior when typing on a physical keyboard. Instead, it affects the behavior of other input mechanisms, such as virtual keyboards on mobile devices and voice input."

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: [Doesn't work in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_autocapitalize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many in the comments have pointed out, the attribute does not affect phisical keyboards. You can achieve this using javascript, by listening to the keyup event and capitalizing the text every time it changes. Here is a working example:

```js
$(".autocapitalize").keyup(function () {
  const originalValue = $(this).val();
  const capitalizedValue = originalValue.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s+\w{1})/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());
  $(this).val(capitalizedValue).focus()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="autocapitalize" autocapitalize="words" name="subject" value="" />
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems that some browsers do not take this attribute into account more "autocapitalize attribute doesn't affect behavior when typing on a physical keyboard".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize

Maybe you should use a function instead.

Comment: what do you mean function? Transform with js? it's not actually the same since in this case we force users use uppercase, but they should be able change register in case they want, and this is how it should works in theory, the same as for native apps. I tried many browsers lol weird attr

Comment: yes you can use change event for update your text value each time a user types.
More the autocapitalize attribute doesn't affect behavior when typing on a physical keyboard.

Comment: This is a comment not a full answer